# Pasar Datos de una Jtable a otra Jtable

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un sistema para una biblioteca, tengo una jtable con los datos de los libros (NombreDelLibro, Autor, Codigo, CantidadDeEjemplares, Editorial) y quiero pasar todos esos datos a otra jtable para que el usuario haga un pedido de libros(que le salgan todos los datos en la segunda jtable y poder pedir el libro seleccionado), soy nuevo y no encuentro un metodo para pasar los datos.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Sin ver código es bieeeen difícil decirte nada. Hay _ideas_ como que mires si tienes un mismo panel con ambos JTable, pues defines el tablemodel correspondiente y tienes un set de datos que manipulas con una y lo pintas con otra, haciendo refresh de acuerdo a algún evento o algo.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder pasar los datos seleccionados de un JTable a otro como mencionas lo que necesitas realizar es lo siguiente, solo adecuarlo tu sistema:

En caso de que no seleccione ningun registro:

```
try{
                 
                 if(tablaEnvia.getSelectedRow() == -1){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No selecciono ningun registro");
                             
                     }
```

Debes obtener el modelo de la tabla que envia los datos y los datos seleccionados por el usuario.
Tambien el modelo de la tablaDestino que es a donde llegaran los datos que vas a pasar.

```
TableModel model = tablaEnvia.getModel();
               int indexs[] = tablaEnvia.getSelectedRows();
                
                Object[] row = new Object[10];
```

Obtienes el modelo de la tablaDestino:

```
DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) tablaDestino.getModel();
```

Con un ciclo for recorres la tabla y este agrega a la tablaDestino los registros seleccionados por el usuario.

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < indexs.length; i++) {
                        row[0] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 0);
                        row[1] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 1);
                        row[2] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 2);
                        row[3] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 3);
                        row[4] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 4);
                        row[5] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 5);
                        row[6] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 6);
                        row[7] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 7);
                        row[8] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 8);
                        row[9] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 9);
                        model2.addRow(row);
                        
                      
    Mandamos una excepcion en caso de algun problema
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No selecciono correctamente registro, verifique e intentelo de nuevo" +ex );
    
    }
        }
```

De esa manera podras realizar lo que ocupas solo adecualo a tu sistema

Comment: Eso donde lo haces? en el boton donde haces la accion de pedir el libro?Gracias

Comment: Si, en el action performed de tu boton, o lo puedes hacer en otro metodo y mandar llamar a ese metodo, si te fue de ayuda puedes votar a favor? saludos...